# Removed some /usr/include/rpcscv headers and .x files by mistake and libnsl.so

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pam

I use archlinux and removed some /usr/include/rpcscv headers and .x files by mistake and libnsl.so.

I know it is stupid, but I don't know how to find them and put them back.

These files are related to PAM so I cannot use su, sudo or pacman and cannot do anything in fact.

I guess I should boot on usb drive and do something, maybe a arch-chroot and force install this with pacman ?

Would following the procedure from this [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/rpcsvc-proto.html) work ?

But will it even be the good version of the lib ?

```
uname -r
```

> 4.15.12-1-ARCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live usb ->
[Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade)
steps 1-3 then

pacman --root=/mnt --cachedir=/mnt/var/cache/pacman/pkg -Qkk

To check which packages are missing files then step 6 to reinstall those packages